# Unable to edit Foreign Key Property

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

RESOLUTION: There were other entities used on the same page that had an fk relationship with meetings, therefore, changing the `meetingid` in the booking table caused a referential integrity error.

I have a parent meeting entity with dependent booking entities. The booking entity has the field `meetingid`, which is the foreign key to the meeting table.

In the view, I have

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.bookings.meetingid)
```

I am able to save the booking entity, updating all of its properties as expected.

Now I want to allow the user to change the `meetingid`, so I've added

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.bookings.meetingid)
```

When I click save, the page posts as normal, but the `meetingid` is unchanged.

I tried removing the hidden `meetingid` field, as it now has the same name as the text field, but this results in a referential integrity error.

This is the post code...

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(vwbooking vwbooking)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.bookings.Attach(vwbooking.bookings);
        vwbooking.bookings.update_date = DateTime.Now;
        vwbooking.bookings.updated_by = User.Identity.Name;
        db.Entry(vwbooking.bookings).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the exception on the `Attach` line it probably means that you have bound some properties of `vwbooking.bookings.meeting` to form fields of the view which cause that `vwbooking.bookings.meeting` gets instantiated in the controller action and that `vwbooking.bookings.meeting.id` is not the same as `vwbooking.bookings.meetingid`. You can then try to solve the problem by changing the Edit action to:

```
var bookingsInDb = db.bookings.Find(vwbooking.bookings.id);
db.Entry(bookingsInDb).CurrentValues.SetValues(vwbooking.bookings);
bookingsInDb.update_date = DateTime.Now;
bookingsInDb.updated_by = User.Identity.Name;
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you get the exception on `SaveChanges` the simple reason might be that a meeting with the entered `meetingid` does not exist in the database.

In any case you need to remove the `HiddenFor`.